# TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len() [BeautifulSoup]

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

i'm trying to login into my college website and then scrap data out of it ,(just the welcome page's sourcecode for the time being) but im getting this this following traceback..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/HUNTER/PycharmProjects/Encryption/erp.py", line 16, in   <module>
   soup = BeautifulSoup(opens, 'lxml')
   File "C:\Users\HUNTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 192, in __init__
   elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
   TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()
```

here is the code..

```
 import requests
 from requests import session
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 url = 'http://erp.college_name.edu/'

 r = requests.session()
 data = {

    'tbUserName': 'username',
    'tbPassword': 'password'

 } 

opens = r.post(url=url, data=data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(opens, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

help is really appriciated..

**UPDATE**

SO, doing,
`soup = BeautifulSoup(opens.text, 'lxml')`
`print(soup)`

gave me this..

```
  C:\Users\HUNTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe     
  C:/Users/HUNTER/PycharmProjects/Encryption/erp.py
  Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\HUNTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-  
     packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 232, in    
    _error_catcher
     yield
    File "C:\Users\HUNTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-   
   32\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 314, in  
   read
   data = self._fp.read(amt)
    File "C:\Users\HUNTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35- 
   32\lib\http\client.py", line 448, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
    File "C:\Users\HUNTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-
  32\lib\http\client.py", line 488, in readinto
     n = self.fp.readinto(b)
   File "C:\Users\HUNTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-
  32\lib\socket.py", line 575, in readinto
   return self._sock.recv_into(b)

   ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was    
   forcibly closed by the remote host


   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\HUNTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-    
      32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 676, in generate
     for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
        File "C:\Users\HUNTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-  
      32\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 357,   
  in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
        File "C:\Users\HUNTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-  

        32\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line  
      324, in read
   flush_decoder = True
        File "C:\Users\HUNTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35- 
      32\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
       File "C:\Users\HUNTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-     
   32\lib\site-   
   packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 250, in   
   _error_catcher
     raise ProtocolError('Connection broken: %r' % e, e)
    requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ("Connection broken:    
ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by    
   the remote host', None, 10054, None)", ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An   
    existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None,    
  10054, None))

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:/Users/HUNTER/PycharmProjects/Encryption/erp.py", line 15, in <module>
opens = r.post(url=url, data=data)
    File "C:\Users\HUNTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-
  32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 522, in post
return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\HUNTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-
 32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
     File "C:\Users\HUNTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-
  32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 628, in send
r.content
    File "C:\Users\HUNTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-
    32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 755, in content
self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or 

bytes()
  File "C:\Users\HUNTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-
     packages\requests\models.py", line 679, in generate
raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)

    requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: 

ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by    

 the    
 remote host', None, 10054, None)", ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing   
 connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

   Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BeautifulSoup requires the returned content, not the complete response. Try using `opens.text`:

```
opens = r.post(url=url, data=data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(opens.text, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Answer (score 0):

i had that error before, and i had the answer.
there are many causes for that error.
This can be caused by the two sides of the connection disagreeing over whether the connection timed out or not during a keepalive.

To examine the problem in detail, you can use Wireshark.

or you can just re-request or re-connect again.